# How to get the Last working day of the Week for any Given date

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I need to calculate Last working day of the Week (Friday) for any date which is given in the excel sheet... Example:: if my date is given as 09-March-2016 the last working day would be 11-March-2016, similarly if my date in Excel cell is 01-March-2016 the Last working day would be 04-March-2016, Can Any one help me with the formula so that I can work further pleaseeeeeeeee... really need your help team :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You will find that it works best if you show, in your question, at least one approach/formulate you've tried, and maybe how it didn't work.  That way, we can help point you in the right direction, if not answer the question directly.

Comment: I agree with @Castaglia please try something and show us what you have done.

Comment: What should the result be if given date is Friday or Saturday?

Answer (score 1):

**In A1 Cell**

01-03-2016

**In B1 Cell**

=A1-WEEKDAY(A1,3)+IF(WEEKDAY(A1,3)>4,11,4)

Answer (score 1):

A1 Cell = Your date (you need last working day in this week)

B1 Cell = A1+(6-WEEKDAY(A1))   - result (in case that friday is last working date)

NOTICE: B1 must be formated as date!